# What is difference between addition assignment operator and plus operator with blank string?

Tags: javascript

I have a code as below:

```js
var point = '';
point = '' + 12 + 34;
console.log(point); // output = 1234
```

```js
var point = '';
point += + 12 + 34;
console.log(point); //output = 46
```

Could you explain about it?

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript has an [arithmetic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic) and a [string operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String) that do entirely different things but use the same symbol (`+`). That's life.

Comment: More about the use of assignment operator as I understand it... http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - JavaScript has one *addition* operator, which varies its action (math vs. concatenation) depending on its operands, not two separate operators with the same glyph: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus

Comment: Main reason is that JavaScript is pure crap :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is grouping. This:

```
point += + 12 + 34;
```

is equivalent to:

```
//              v-----------v---- note grouping
point = point + ( + 12 + 34 );
//                ^--- unary
```

The indicated `+` is a unary `+` which doesn't do anything there since `12` is already a number. So we have:

```
point = point + ( 12 + 34 );
```

which is:

```
point = point + 46;
```

which, since `point` starts out being `""`, is `"46"` (a string).

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, this is what happens:

1. `'' + 12 --> '12'` (notice that now we have a string, as opposed to a number)
2. `'12' + 34 --> '1234'` Javascript automatically coerces the number 34 to the string `'34'` in order to evaluate the expression

Instead, this is what happens in the second case:

1. `+12 --> 12` unary operator applied to the number `12`, nothing happens
2. `12 + 34 --> 46` pretty standard sum
3. `'' + 46 --> '46'` empty string summed to the number `46`, which results in the string `'46'`

Answer (score 4):

Per [Addition Assignment Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/addition-assignment-operator-decrement-equal-javascript)...

> Using this operator is exactly the same as specifying: `result = result + expression`.

Your *expression* is `+12 + 34`, which evaluates to the integer `46`.

```
point = point + expression
point = point + (+12 + 34)
point = point + 46
point = ""    + 46
point = "46"
```

---

You may notice that in the final step, `""` combined with `46` gave us a *string* `"46"`. Again, per the aforementioned documentation...

> The types of the two expressions determine the behavior of the += operator:

```
If                                                         Then
---                                                        ---
Both expressions are numeric or Boolean                    Add
Both expressions are strings                               Concatenate
One expression is numeric and the other is a string        Concatenate
```

This would be an example of the third case. One expression is numeric (`46`) and the other is a string (`""`), so these two values concatenate to `"46"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
The addition assignment operator `(+=)` adds a value to a variable.
`x += y` means  `x = x + y`
The `+=` assignment operator can also be used to add (concatenate) strings:

Example: 

    txt1 = "What a very ";
    txt1 += "nice day";

The result of txt1 will be:

    What a very nice day

On the other hand adding empty String `''` will make javascript to
confuse Addition & Concatenation.
Addition is about adding numbers.
Concatenation is about adding strings.



    var x = 10 + 5;          // the result in x is 15
    var x = 10 + "5";        // the result in x is "105"
```

Comment: avoid making a code sample format to the text that are not a code. Use CTRL+K to make your code to be a code sample format.